# VirtualBox createvm in Dockerfile fails

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, docker, ubuntu-20.04, dev

I'm trying to create a Dockerfile that has a VirtualBox VM inside: it's based on `ubuntu20.04` and I first install and setup the packages:

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04
...
RUN echo 'debconf debconf/frontend select Noninteractive' | debconf-set-selections
RUN apt-get -y update
RUN apt-get -y install apt-utils dialog
RUN apt-get -y upgrade
RUN apt-get -y install -y virtualbox-dkms linux-headers-generic
RUN dpkg-reconfigure virtualbox
```

which all goes fine. But then when I try to run

```
RUN VBoxManage createvm --name windows --register --basefolder /vbox/vms
```

I get this error:

```
WARNING: The character device /dev/vboxdrv does not exist.
         Please install the virtualbox-dkms package and the appropriate
         headers, most likely linux-headers-generic.

         You will not be able to start VMs until this problem is fixed.
```

All subsequent calls to `VBoxManage` show this same warning, and nothing in the way of VM is set up.

I have added all the extra `debconf`, `apt` and `dpkg` calls that I could find, but it seems that to set up the VM, the link from `/dev/vboxdrv` to the host's `/dev/vboxdrv` needs to be present, but the options `--device` and `-v` are not allowed with `docker build`. Looks like a catch-22?

Is it possible to call `VBoxManage` in a Dockerfile?

Answer (score 0):

The answer seems to be embarrassingly simple: if the character device does not exist, for the moment just create it as a stub.

The developer of the [vboxmanage-docker](https://github.com/3mdeb/vboxmanage-docker) repository on GitHub already knew this, so this is a re-post.